# Get LightGBM/ LGBM run with GPU on Google Colabratory

Tags: python, gpu, google-colaboratory, lightgbm

I often run LGBM on Google Colabratory and I just found out this page saying that LGBM it set to CPU by default so you need to set up first.
https://medium.com/@am.sharma/lgbm-on-colab-with-gpu-c1c09e83f2af
So I executed the code recommended on the page or some other codes recommended on stackoverflow as follows,

`!git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM
%cd LightGBM
!mkdir build
%cd build
!cmake ../../LightGBM
!make -j4
!git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM.git
%cd LightGBM/python-package
!python3 setup.py install --gpu
!pip install cmake`

But I still get an Error

`GPU Tree Learner was not enabled in this build.Please recompile with CMake option -DUSE_GPU=1`

How can I fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you resolved your issue? Please see the answer below and mark it if it works for you.

Comment: Perhaps this might help : https://www.thekerneltrip.com/machine-learning/lgbmgpu/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After running

```
! git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM
```

You can run this oneliner which will build and compile LightGBM with GPU enabled in colab:

```
! cd LightGBM && rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build && cmake -DUSE_GPU=1 ../../LightGBM && make -j4 && cd ../python-package && python3 setup.py install --precompile --gpu;
```

Hope that helps ;D

Comment: Doesn't work. Colab says it's not utilizing GPU.

Comment: @user8491363, it worked for me, did you pass `device_type='gpu'` to the LGBM model?

Comment: This worked for me (16th Mar 2023).  Be aware Colab caches packages, so you may have to restart the runtime to make sure the newly-installed lightgbm is being imported, and not the old one.

Comment: For me the installation always ends with 
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/LightGBM/python-package/lightgbm/VERSION.txt'`