# lightgbm GPU install not working in Colab

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory, lightgbm

I'm trying to install lightgbm with GPU support in colab, but every method I've tried ends up causing LightGBM to produce an error message stating that unexpected keyword arguments are being used (e.g., early_stopping_rounds) when I attempt to train the model. If I try it without including the kwarg that caused the error, it just returns the same error message for a different one that's still included. The code works totally fine when I run it with the pre-loaded version of lightgbm that is included in colab envs, but any attempt I've made to install the package with GPU support leads to this error if the installation is successful.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Here's the most recent method I followed to install lgbm with gpu support enabled:

```
! git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM

! cd LightGBM && rm -rf build && mkdir build && cd build && cmake -DUSE_GPU=1 ../../LightGBM && make -j4 && cd ../python-package && python3 setup.py install --precompile --gpu;

%cd /content/LightGBM/python-package

!python3 setup.py install --gpu
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not entirely sure why, but it is working now. I installed following the instructions in this stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58707252/get-lightgbm-lgbm-run-with-gpu-on-google-colabratory). Same as before, but only difference is I ran the colab notebook on my iMac instead of macbook. Not sure what difference that would make since my understanding is colab shouldn't be influenced by the local system, but alas, here we are.

Comment: well, actually it isn't working. The model will start training the first fold for the CV, but it will never actually do anything. Stuck at "[LightGBM] [Info] Start training from score -x.xxxxx" ... runs fine on CPU with the same code (apart from GPU params and install)